# Shared object symbol resolution

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, symbols

Suppose I have 2 static Libs `S1` and `S2` which are different versions of the same lib and have the same C (not C++) interface though implementations are different. 2 shared libs `D1` and `D2` each of which links to `S1` or `S2` only. Suppose an application `A` links with `S2` which is the more recent of the static libs and dynamically loads both `D1` and `D2` with `dlopen`. Will `D1` just use `S1`s functions or is there any way to enforce it to use `S2`s functions? Can anything go wrong in this setup?

EDIT: Is making a shared object `S` a good way to circumvent this problem as `D1` and `D2` can both link to `S` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will `D1` just use `S1`s functions or is there any way to enforce it to use `S2`s functions?

Yes, `D1` will use `S1` functions.
No, you cannot enforce it to use `S2` functions.

> Can anything go wrong in this setup?

It depends on what is inside your libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by what is inside libraries? It is not clear to me.

Comment: I mean it depends on what is inside `S1` and `S2`. If they have global static data for example, it will not be shared between the two. This may or may not be what you want.